# Pandas: Specifying column labels when creating DataFrame returns NaN

Tags: python, pandas

The code below returns a dataframe with NaN values.

```
my_columns = ['Current', 'In 6 Months', 'Under Stress']
my_index = ['Liquid Assets', 'Cash & Short Duration Bonds', 'Illiquid Assets']
combined_df = pd.DataFrame([curr_data, in6m_data, understress_data], index = my_index, columns = my_columns)
```

While this works perfectly.

```
my_columns = ['Current', 'In 6 Months', 'Under Stress']
my_index = ['Liquid Assets', 'Cash & Short Duration Bonds', 'Illiquid Assets']
combined_df = pd.DataFrame([curr_data, in6m_data, understress_data], index = my_index)
combined_df.columns = my_columns


curr_data
0    4.490472e+09
1    2.911620e+08
2    6.931839e+08
Name: Current, dtype: float64

in6m_data
0    4.031035e+09
1    2.910907e+08
2    5.764309e+08
Name: In 6 Months, dtype: float64

understress_data
0    8.127460e+08
1    3.324597e+08
2    2.656221e+09
Name: Under Stress, dtype: float64
```

Anyone know the why/difference?

Comment: I tried running the code with dummy numbers and it works fine.  Something about curr_data, in6m_data, and understress_data.

Comment: What's the version of `pandas` are you using? I just tested out your code and it works fine on my end.

Comment: Not sure.  I'm running Anaconda 1.8.0 (python 2.7.5).

Comment: That... is severely outdated. Anaconda is already at 2.1.0. Try doing `import pandas` then `print pandas.__version__` on your command line. For reference, I'm using the latest Anaconda distro running Python 2.7.8 with the latest `pandas` as well.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Version 0.12.0